# How to get list of jobs started by pipeline in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I trying to write system groovy script in Jenkins with this function:

1. User input name of the job/pipeline.
2. A user gets the list of the build numbers and selects one.
3. Then every job run by parent job will be marked as Keep forever.

I am stuck with getting the list of all jobs run by parent build. I can get the list of builds:

```
println jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("SandBox/TEST_keep_builds_forever_pipeline").builds.displayName
```

Output is: [#10, #9, #8, #7, #6]

Had anyone done this before?

Comment: I believe you are going to have to retrieve the step graph and process it to see which downstream jobs were executed for a particular run.